# Issue accessing MySQL connector jar file in tomcat/lib directory

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, classpath, jndi

I can't seem to get Tomcat 8 running on Ubuntu to load the mysql jar file from the `tomcat/lib` directory.  Here's the list of the mysql jar in `tomcat/lib` dir:

```
-rwxrwxr-x 1 root root  989497 Jul 22 12:39 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39-bin.jar
```

Here's the context.xml setting with names changed to protect the guilty.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<Context>
    <Resource name="jdbc/waterwings" auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource" driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/waterwings?verifyServerCertificate=false&amp;useSSL=false&amp;useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&amp;useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&amp;serverTimezone=UTC"
        username="user" password="password"/>
</Context>
```

Test app jsp:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/sql" prefix="sql" %>     
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<sql:query var="pings" dataSource="jdbc/waterwings">
    select count(*) from pings;
</sql:query>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Users List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="center">
            <h2>Ping Count</h2>
            ${ping.count}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

test app web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
     <description>DB Connection</description>
     <res-ref-name>jdbc/waterwings</res-ref-name>
     <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
     <res-auth>Container</res-auth>  
</resource-ref>
```

Error message:

```
ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/waterwings"] with root cause
 javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: Unable to get connection, DataSource invalid: "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc/waterwings"
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.getConnection(QueryTagSupport.java:276)
at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.sql.QueryTagSupport.doStartTag(QueryTagSupport.java:159)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_sql_005fquery_005f0(index_jsp.java:177)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:124)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:438)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:528)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1099)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:670)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1520)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1476)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any ideas would be mucho appreciado.

Comment: What is the error message? Btw. in JSP (and web.xml), you use `jdbc/waterwings` datasource, but `jdbc/wwdb` is declared in context.xml.

Comment: Sorry that was my changing the names.  They all line up for the lookup name.  I've added the error message.

Comment: It's (seems to be) quite clear: Tomcat for some reason does not recognize mysql driver JAR file in `tomcat/lib`, so you have to put it into `WEB-INF/lib` of your web application.

Comment: I don't think that will work when using the data source as a JNDI resource.  The container will need the driver to connect, which is the point of using JNDI. I'd have to change my persistence layer to manage their own connections and resource pools instead of letting the container handle it.  There has to be a solution.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Well, you have to find out, why it ignores the file where it is now.